# How to test disk latency on Linux?

Tags: linux, performance, raid

Made an upgrade of RAID firmware and latency as it seems have increased.

Could you please advise on the most accurate way to examine disk read and write latencies?

Comment: time command can be used. copy a big file and calculate how much time it taking

Comment: Look at this question: [Linux Tool command to check file system performance](http://serverfault.com/questions/233836/linux-tool-command-to-check-file-system-performance/233840#233840)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IOzone](http://www.iozone.org/) great benchmark.

Run Random Read, Random Write, Random Mix test to check latencies.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using `fio` as I described in answer https://askubuntu.com/a/991311/50254

The `fio` allows you to get more info about the distribution of latencies for different work loads (anything between single threaded huge sequential writes QD32 and mixed random read and write 4k QD1 with multiple threads).

I think that if you assume that hardware has higher latency than previously, you should test single threaded random 4k read QD1 (this is the most latency sensitive operation that I can think):

`fio --name TEST --eta-newline=5s --filename=fio-tempfile.dat --rw=randread --size=500m --io_size=10g --blocksize=4k --ioengine=libaio --fsync=1 --iodepth=1 --direct=1 --numjobs=1 --runtime=60 --group_reporting`

That will create test file `fio-tempfile.dat` in the current working directory so make sure that you first change to device you want to test. (If you want to test raw device performance instead of performance with a file system, you can use raw device as the `filename`. You're going to lose current contents of said device, though.)

You can also test the same thing with writing instead of reading data:

`fio --name TEST --eta-newline=5s --filename=fio-tempfile.dat --rw=randwrite --size=500m --io_size=10g --blocksize=4k --ioengine=libaio --fsync=1 --iodepth=1 --direct=1 --numjobs=1 --runtime=60 --group_reporting`

If you see huge increase in latency with write you can be pretty sure that old firmware allowed write back cache and the new firmware does not allow that. Unless you have battery backed RAID controller or correctly configured UPS, you do not want write back cache if you consider your data important.

Comment: Note that `--fsync=1` will have no effect for read-only test but I left the flag there to keep two example cases as close to identical as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The common tool in Linux hard disk tuning and basic performance monitoring is [`hdparm`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdparm).

Comment: hdparm is nice, but forker asks for latency and hdparm can't show it

Answer (score 2):

you can use `dd` to mesure the latency of a disk

eg.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/testfile bs=512 count=1000 oflag=dsync
```

Comment: I you are gonna give half of an answer, better include the description of the article you copied this from: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_I/O_Performance_Tests_using_dd

`e.g. In this test, 512 bytes were written one thousand times. Thereby, the 0.084 seconds that were measured for one thousand accesses corresponded to precisely 0.084 ms for each access.`

Comment: @goetzc feel free to edit my answer directly.

Answer (score 0):

**Disk Latency Attestation Tool**

A simple yet effective tool to track disk storage latency during write operations.

This utility operates as a daemon in the RAM, generates random data and writes it as a file to the specified disk storage for a certain intervals, measuring the time it took to write a file of the same size in every reiteration.

The data cannot being cached because for each new test of writing pseudo-random data is generated.

The application generates a log in the form of a CSV table, detailing the date, time of each event, duration of dataset writing, error codes and error messages.

[Project Page of Disk Latency Attestation Tool](https://github.com/eitijupaenoithoowohd/disk_latency_attestation)

Answer (score 0):

For testing disk latency, I use two utilities: [`ioping`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/ioping/ioping.1.en.html) and [`fio`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/fio/fio.1.en.html)

`ioping` is the disk I/O equivalent of `ping`. It is very useful for a rapid first-pass on the disk subsystem. Running `ioping -C -D -G /your/dir` results in the following output, where `<<<` means reading and `>>>` means writing:

```
4 KiB >>> /root/test/ (xfs /dev/dm-0 32.0 GiB): request=1 time=2.90 ms (warmup)
4 KiB <<< /root/test/ (xfs /dev/dm-0 32.0 GiB): request=2 time=278.4 us
4 KiB >>> /root/test/ (xfs /dev/dm-0 32.0 GiB): request=3 time=23.2 ms
4 KiB <<< /root/test/ (xfs /dev/dm-0 32.0 GiB): request=4 time=283.5 us
4 KiB >>> /root/test/ (xfs /dev/dm-0 32.0 GiB): request=5 time=6.29 ms
```

For a more intensive test (ie: akin to ping flood), add `-R` to the commands above. For testing sync writes, remove `-C`

`fio` is invaluable for in-depth analysis. Use `fio --name=test --filename=/your/file --rw=randrw --size=256M --direct=1 --runtime=15` for a quick first pass. Add `--sync=1` for testing sync writes. Example output:

```
...
read: IOPS=3708, BW=14.5MiB/s (15.2MB/s)(128MiB/8828msec)
  clat (usec): min=90, max=12403, avg=200.61, stdev=385.19
   lat (usec): min=90, max=12403, avg=200.79, stdev=385.20
...
write: IOPS=3715, BW=14.5MiB/s (15.2MB/s)(128MiB/8828msec); 0 zone resets
  clat (usec): min=32, max=16906, avg=65.05, stdev=317.08
   lat (usec): min=32, max=16906, avg=65.33, stdev=317.09
...
```

Bonus point: ZFS does not supports true `O_DIRECT` read/writes, so non-sync writes are going to be cached. Reads will be cached unless setting `primarycache=none` on the testing dataset. Anyway ZFS performance testing, due to its strong reliance on ARC and other factors, [is a quite complex task.](https://serverfault.com/questions/1021251/fio-benchmarking-inconsistent-and-slower-than-anticipated-are-my-raids-miscon)