# FIO Benchmarking - Inconsistent and Slower than Anticipated: Are my RAIDs Misconfigured?

Tags: raid, storage, zfs, proxmox, dell-perc

**TL;DR:** I'm having some performance issues with my hypervisor storage. here are a bunch of test results from `fio`. Skip to the `Results` section to read about them and see my questions.

---

**Summary**

I recently purchased an R730xd so before I migrate over to it I wanted to be sure that storage was performing opmtimally. I've been running some benchmark tests with [fio](https://github.com/axboe/fio) and have found some alarming results. Using a combination of those results and [fio-plot](https://github.com/louwrentius/fio-plot), I've amassed a pretty large collection of graphs and charts that demonstrate the issues across my various storage backends.

However, I'm having a hard time turning it into usable *information* because I don't have anything to compare it to. And I think I'm having some very strange performance issues.

---

**Disk Configuration**

Here are the four types of storage exposed to my hypervisor (Proxmox):

```
╔═══════════╦════════════════════════════════╦═════════════╦════════════════════════════╗
║  Storage  ║            Hardware            ║ Filesystem  ║        Description         ║
╠═══════════╬════════════════════════════════╬═════════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║ SATADOM   ║ 1x Dell K9R5M SATADOM          ║ LVM/XFS     ║ Hypervisor filesystem      ║
║ FlashPool ║ 2x Samsung 970 EVO M.2 SSD     ║ ZFS RAID 1  ║ Hypervisor Compute Storage ║
║ DataPool  ║ 6x HGST 7200RPM HDD            ║ ZFS RAID 10 ║ Redundant Data Storage     ║
║ RAIDPool  ║ 6x Seagate/Hitachi 7200RPM HDD ║ HW RAID 10  ║ General Purpose Storage    ║
╚═══════════╩════════════════════════════════╩═════════════╩════════════════════════════╝
```

---

**Storage Details**

Here is a more detailed breakdown for each storage backend:

1. **SATADOM**: The `SATADOM` is managed directly by Proxmox via LVM. [Here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zimmertr/be92c2ef7e5b86cadc817ff442652aff) is the output from `lvdisplay pve`. The SATADOM is connected to the server via the internal DVD-ROM SATA port as it is unused in the `R730xd` model.
2. **FlashPool**: The `FlashPool` is a simple ZFS RAID 1 comprised of dual NVMe SSDs. The goal is to use this as backing storage for my VMs. [Here](https://gist.github.com/zimmertr/d2ad3968df20468cbbbc08ee4589fe75) are the outputs for:

   ```
    zpool list  
    zpool status  
    zfs get all
   ```

   Each of the SSDs in the `FlashPool` are connected to the server via [PCI-E -> M.2 adapters](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B07JKH5VTL/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) installed in x16 PCIe slots. I recognize that these are x4 PCIe adapters. However, I'm pretty sure NVMe only operates at that speed so faster adapters are not manufactured.
3. **DataPool**: The `DataPool` is the only pre-existing dataset. It is a couple years old and was previously used for both Data and VM storage to the detriment of performance.  It is also managed by Proxmox as a ZFS RAID 10.

   It was originally comprised of `6x 4TB HGST Ultrastar 7K4000 7200RPM` disks. However, as they started to fail I decided to replace them with higher density disks. As a result, the array now consists of:

   ```
    2x 6TB HGST Ultrastar He6 7200RPM  
    4x 4TB HGST Ultrastar 7K4000 7200RPM
   ```

   I obviously intend to eventually move entirely to 6TB disks as the older ones continue to fail. [Here](https://gist.github.com/zimmertr/cbeb835cc89a285111eaba6165057386) are the outputs for the same commands posted above for the `FlashPool`.

   These 6 disks are connected to the server via the first 6 bays on the backplane. This backplane is connected to a Dell H730 Mini PERC RAID Controller.
4. **RAIDPool**: The `RAIDPool` is an experimental storage backend. I've never worked with hardware RAID before so I was excited for the opportunity now that I have a proper RAID Controller. Similar to the `DataPool`, these disks are installed in the last 6 bays on the backplane. However, instead of being passed through to Proxmox, they are managed by the PERC. They are presented to Proxmox as a single disk which is then managed by LVM and presented to the OS via logical volumes as XFS filesystems. [Here](https://gist.github.com/zimmertr/84b5531cf282cfb6a0b55629d17f9af5) is the output from `lvdisplay RAIDPool`.

---

**RAID Controller Configuration**

So, you may have just noticed that both the `DataPool` and `RAIDPool` are installed and managed by the H730 RAID Controller. However, the `DataPool` is managed by Proxmox via ZFS and the `RAIDPool` is managed by the actual controller.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICQv5.png) is a screenshot of the topology of the physical disks. The H730 is capable of passing disks directly through to the OS and simultaneously managing other disks. As you can see, The first 6 disks are configured in `Non-RAID` mode and the last 6 disks are configured in `Online` mode.

- [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxax6.png) are the configured properties for the controller from within the iDRAC UI.
- Disk Cache is enabled for both Write Back and Read Ahead on the Virtual Disk (`RAIDPool`). Since this is configured specifically for the VD, it should not impact the ZFS drives.
- [Dick Cache for Non-RAID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwucB.png) disks (ZFS `DataPool`) is set to `Disable`.
- The [Link Speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI5Yz.png) for all of the drives is set to `auto`.

Also, after stepping through all of the settings once more, I enabled `Write Cache` for the Embedded SATA Controller. So this might improve performance on the `SATADOM` from what is seen in the benchmarks below.

---

**Benchmarking:**

I have benchmarked all of these storage backends in two ways. For both tests, I ran a series of `fio-plot` commands in a [small shell script](https://gist.github.com/zimmertr/64029d851a7257271584c704252d183e) that dumped the results in a few folders.

If you're crazy and want to parse through the raw results on your own, [here they are](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yd4_D2WJZKlZOoVZEMR_JH6Y6x7Ux6YK/view?usp=sharing). You will need to massage my scripts a bit to rerun then since I moved around the directory structure to organize it prior to uploading it.

In a nutshell, they ran a series of tests against each storage backend that evaluated its *RANDOM* bandwidth, IOPS, and latency. It then plotted these results on graphs. Some graphs compare multiple backends. Other graphs simply show results from individual backends. I did not perform any *SEQUENTIAL* tests. In all cases, the default block size was used for the test.

**Test 1)** From within Proxmox, I mounted all of the storage backends into the `/mnt` directory. The ZFS Pool were simply imported into the OS and both the RAIDPool and the `SATADOM` were presented to the OS via LVM. Each had a Logical Volume formatted as an XFS partition that was used for benchmarking. NOTE: I ran these benchmarks from the live OS so the performance of the `SATADOM` will be affected accordingly.

- [Comparison Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFXav.jpg)
- [Individual Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmpog.jpg)

The log files were generated using these commands:

```
./bench_fio --target /mnt/SATADOM_Data/bm --type directory --size 450M --mode randread randwrite --output SATADOM
./bench_fio --target /mnt/RAIDPool_Data/bm --type directory --size 1G --mode randread randwrite --output RAIDPOOL
./bench_fio --target /mnt/DataPool/bm/ --type directory --size 1G --mode randread randwrite --output DATAPOOL
./bench_fio --target /mnt/FlashPool/bm/ --type directory --size 1G --mode randread randwrite --output FLASHPOOL
```

**Test 2)** I created three VMs in Proxmox. Each of which used a different backing storage from the `FlashPool`, `DataPool`, and `RAIDPool`. The `FlashPool` and DataPool VMs ran in their own ZFS dataset. The `RAIDPool` VM ran on its own thick-provisioned Logical Volume. All three VMs were given 4 vCPUs and 40GB of memory.

- [Comparison Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ43U.jpg)
- [Individual Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxcwT.jpg)

The log files were generated using these commands:

```
./bench_fio     --target /fio     --type file     --size 1G     --mode randread randwrite     --duration 600     --output DATAPOOL_VM
./bench_fio     --target /fio     --type file     --size 1G     --mode randread randwrite     --duration 600     --output RAIDPOOL_VM
./bench_fio     --target /fio     --type file     --size 1G     --mode randread randwrite     --duration 600     --output FLASHPOOL_VM
```

---

**Results:**

The graphs in the above Imgur links should all be in the same order. The results from the two benchmarks are quite a bit different. But that is to be expected when you factor in the overhead from virtualization. What is NOT expected to me, is that they all seem to behave about the same.

- For example, [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3spUU.png) shows that when `fio` was run from within a VM, the average write bandwidth was somewhere around 125 MB/s. Shouldn't the two NVMe SSDs in RAID 1 (`FlashPool`) MASSIVELY outperform the `SATADOM`? Instead, you can see that the `FlashPool` VM took the LONGEST amount of time to complete the test and had the slowest average write bandwidth. The same situation can be seen for the [Write IOPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAo73.png) comparison -- The average IOPS were around 3,000 and the `FlashPool` VM took the longest to execute the test!
- Stepping away from the benchmarks taken from WITHIN a VM, and instead looking at those taken by directly interacting with the storage from the hypervisor, we can see some different behavior. For example, [in this test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoWet.png) the write bandwidth for the `FlashPool` and `DataPool` was as high as 400MB/s. However, the performance for the `RAIDPool` averaged around 10MB/s. Which coincidentally, was about the same as the `SATADOM`? Surely, the `RAIDPool` should have performed compatible to, if not better than, the `DataPool`? Given that they are comprised of similar disks present in the same RAID Controller? Similar to above, the [Write IOPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFhP6.png) show the same bizarre story.
- [The Write Latency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmCow.png) from the Hypervisor tests also appears to be unusual. The `RAIDPool` appears to be experiencing up to ten times worse latency than the ZFS Pools? However, if you flip over to the [VM tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKb3b.png), the latency for the three storage backends seems to congregate around 300us. Which is pretty similar to what we were seeing in the WORST cast for the `RAIDPool`. Why does this smooth effect happen to write latency when the tests are run from VMs instead of hypervisor? Why does the latency for the ZFS Pools suddenly become so much worse, and comparable to, the `RAIDPool`?
- Looking at the read Bandwidth, IOPS, and latency shows a similar story. All metrics are equally slow, despite having massively different hardware configurations, when benchmarked from within a VM. However, once benchmarked from the hypervisor, the ZFS Pools suddenly greatly outperform everything else?

  - [Read Bandwidth 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3YYo.png)
  - [Read Bandwidth 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ge8m.png)
  - [Read IOPS 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHk6W.png)
  - [Read IOPS 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOqFm.png)
  - [Read Latency 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7nZn.png)
  - [Read Latency 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6N0E.png)

---

**Questions:**

1. These results are abnormal... right? [This](http://images.anandtech.com/doci/13761/rw-s-970evo-1000.png) benchmark from [this](https://www.anandtech.com/show/13761/the-samsung-970-evo-plus-ssd-review/6) website shows a 970 EVO achieving upwards of 900MB/s random write speeds. Why are mine only coming in at [150MB/s on the hypervisor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW9Gf.png) and [10MB/s in a VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7emrq.png)? Why are these speeds so different when benchmarked from the hypervisor and from a VM?
2. Why does the `RAIDPool` suddenly become abnormally slow when benchmarked from the Hypervisor? [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha0Ij.png) we see that the Read Bandwidth in a VM averages 20MB/s. However, from the [hypervisor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5CE1.png), it instead reports 4MB/s. Just like the benchmark tests I showed in question 1, shouldn't these read speeds be closer to [900MB/s](http://images.anandtech.com/doci/13761/rr-s-970evo-1000.png)?
3. Why do the ZFS Pools suddenly perform significantly worse when benchmarked from within a VM instead of the hypervisor? For example, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHaNl.png) we can see that the read IOPS averaged around 200,000 and latency under 650us. However, when benchmarked from [within a VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rZPN.png), we can suddenly see that the read IOPS average around 2,500 and the latency more than quadrupled? Shouldn't the performance in both situations be about the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When benchmarking ZFS pools, you need to understand how caching and recordsize interact with your workloads:

- your `fio` commands do not skip the linux pagecache (no `--direct=1` option), nor ZFS ARC. However, due the different mode of operation between the two, you can end favoring a plain filesystem (XFS) vs ZFS or vice-versa. To mitigate the caching effect, I suggest you benchmarking with a file 2x greater than your RAM value (ie: if having 24 GB of RAM, use a 48 GB file). Do *not* benchmark ZFS with caching disabled (ie: `primarycache=none`), as a CoW filesystem *needs* an high cache hit rate to give good performance (especially when writing less-than-recordsize blocks, as you can read below);
- your random read/write IOPs and thoughtput are going to be severely affected by ZFS `recordsize` property, as ZFS generally transfers full recordsized blocks (with the exception of small files, where "small" means < recordsize). In other words, while `fio` is reading/writing 4K blocks, ZFS actually read/write 32K blocks *for each 4K block* requested by `fio`. Caching can (and will) alter this generic rule, but the point remains: with large recordsize, throughput saturation can be a thing. Please note that I am *not* stating that 32K recordsize is unreasonable (albeit I would probably use 16K to limit wear on the SSDs); however, you need to account for it when evaluating the benchmark results;
- I would re-enable the physical disk cache for the pass-through disks as ZFS knows how to flush their volatile cache. However, you need to check that your H730P honours ATA FLUSHes / FUAs for pass-though disks (it *should* pass syncs, but its manual is unclear on this point and I have no actual hardware to try);
- your `RAIDPool` array is composed of mechanical HDDs, so its random read performance are going to be low (the controller cache will not help you for random reads).

All considerend, I don't find your results to be abnormal; rather, they do not represent a valid workload and are partially misinterpreted. If you really want to compare ZFS and HWRAID+XFS, I suggest you to test with an actual expected workload (ie: a database + application VMs doing some useful works) while at the same time being sure to use [ThinLVM](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmthin.7.html) (rather than classical LVM) to have at least a fast-snapshot capability somewhat comparable to ZFS own snapshot/clone features.

But, in a sense, you can avoid doing these tests, simply because the outcome will be quite predictable:

- a plain HWRAID+LVM+XFS setup will be faster for sequential IO and random read/writes on datasets which fits into the linux pagecache: not being affected by CoW, it pays a much smaller overhead than ZFS;
- the ZFS setup will be faster in real-world scenarios where the scan-resistant nature of ARC will ensure the most frequently used data remain always cached. Moreover, compression and checksumming are two killer features (to have similar features from HWRAID you need to use a stacked `dm-integrity` + `vdo` + `thinlvm` setup, which itself commands a great performance penalty).

As a reference point, I recently replaced a Dell R720xd featuring a H710P + 12 10K RPM SAS disks with a much cheaper SuperMicro 5029WTR featuring 2x SSD (for boot and L2ARC) + 1x NVMe Optane (for SLOG) and 6x 7.2K RPM SATA disks. The SuperMicro system, while having only 1/3 the nominal random read performance than the Dell one, performs much better thanks to ARC/L2ARC and compression.

In the end, while I fully understand the motivations to use a classical HWRAID+LVM+XFS system, I would not go back to using it rather than ZFS for a bare metal machine as an hypervisor (unless targeting specific workloads which really badly perform with a CoW layer in between or when extreme speed and DirectIO are required - see XFS `dax` option).

Comment: This is such a fantastic answer. You have taught me a lot. Thank you so much for taking the time to think through and write this.